# Thick border of drawn string

Tags: java, string, draw

Now I feel like I've been looking all over the internet to find out how to add a border on a text, so I decided to ask here, since you guys always knows the answer.

So, how do I, in java,  draw a border of approx 2 pixels around every letter in a string drawn on a Graphics2D element ?

Like this:
[image: Text with 2px border]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See: [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html). Set the "primitive" to "text" and the "rendering" to "Stroke and Fill" in the transform example.

Answer (score 7):

I found one simple solution in [Javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip81.html) for drawing an outline on text in Java:

> ```
> g.setColor(Color.red);
> g.drawString("Outline", ShiftWest(x, 1), ShiftNorth(y, 1));
> g.drawString("Outline", ShiftWest(x, 1), ShiftSouth(y, 1));
> g.drawString("Outline", ShiftEast(x, 1), ShiftNorth(y, 1));
> g.drawString("Outline", ShiftEast(x, 1), ShiftSouth(y, 1));
> g.setColor(Color.yellow);
> g.drawString("Outline", x, y);
> ```

Essentially, you draw the same string shifted in each direction first before you draw the string in the desired color. This works well for a one pixel outline, but does not scale well to thick outlines as there may be gaps in the corners if you repeat the shifting multiple times.

Another solution would be to use a transformation and getOutline() which is a method of the TextLayout class. An example for doing outline can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/OutlineFontpaint.htm).

Comment: Not quite there... it misses the UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT, but it's a very nice solution. I'm gonna use it.

Comment: I think this is certainly an easy solution for a simple border outline. +1